# Why doesn't the Flink SocketTextStreamWordCount work?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've set up the example project and built it. I'm able to run the WordCount program as expected. But when I run the SocketTextWordCount, I'm not getting any results printed out.

- I send data in through nc (localhost:9999 on both sides)
- In the web console for the running job, I can see that there are messages being sent/received

But I never see the counts.print() output printed out anywhere, even after killing the nc session.

EDIT - when I change it around to print results to a text file, no problem. So the issue seems to be that counts.print() isn't properly writing to the stdout of the console I'm running the example in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DataStreams are printed to the standard-out of the TaskManager process. When starting a Flink instance (local or cluster), the standard-out of a TaskManager is directed into an `.out` file in the `./log/` directory of the Flink root directory. So you should check if the output is written into these files.

This behavior is different from `DataSet.print()`, where the results are collected on the JobManager, shipped to the client, and printed by the client.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a bunch.